# Splunk: Schedule alert to run every 10 minutes

Tags: alert, splunk

I want to set an alert which runs every 10 minutes and is triggered when a certain ratio is either bigger than 2.5 or smaller than 0.5.

```
"certainEvent" source="abc.log" 
| timechart partial=f span=5m count as numbers 
| fillnull 
| streamstats current=f last(numbers) as last_numbers 
| eval ratio = numbers/last_numbers 
| where ratio>2.5 OR ratio < 0.5
```

Now I want to schedule the alert search to run every 10 minutes. Therefore, I want to run it on cron schedule and chose `*/10 * * * *`. Is that correct?

Secondly, I can choose an expiration date and a Time Range in the **Save as Alert**-menu. By default it seems to be set to the last 24 hours (Time Range) and Expiration date as well to the last 24 hours. I am now wondering if these settings do have an effect on the alert search. I do not want my alert search to find every event which fulfills the condition in the query I set upon every time in this time range but only once (and then get informed by mail). I also do not want the alert to expire after 24 hours but let the alert search run until it is stopped by me or someone else. So, I am wondering if I should or have to modify these two parameters in order to get the required functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now I want to schedule the alert search to run every 10 minutes. Therefore, I want to run it on cron schedule and chose `*/10 * * * *`. Is that correct?

Yes, that will run it every 10 minutes

> Secondly, I can choose an expiration date and a Time Range in the Save as Alert-menu. By default it seems to be set to the last 24 hours (Time Range) and Expiration date as well to the last 24 hours. I am now wondering if these settings do have an effect on the alert search.

That's how long the *results of the given search* are saved before expiring them

The time period over which the search runs is set in the search itself. I usually *explicitly* set the period with `earliest=` thusly:

```
index=ndx sourcetype=srctp fieldA=* fieldb=* earliest=-10m
```

> I also do not want the alert to expire after 24 hours but let the alert search run until it is stopped by me or someone else.

I think you misunderstand many Splunk terms. A search will run until it finishes. The *results* of a search are only kept for however-long the expiration time is set for that search (defaults include 10 minutes, 7 days, 24 hours, and 2x the run interval (eg for scheduled Reports)).

If you schedule an Alert, it will stay scheduled until you (or someone else with appropriate permissions) disable it - I've got Alerts that run every 30 minutes that have been in place for *months*. I've got others that used to run every hour, but are now disabled (but not deleted, because we need them around during some parts of the year).

Comment: Thank you! Regarding your first answer -> I found this: https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/8.1.1/Alert/CronExpressions. And there it is stated that `*/9 * * * *` means "every nine minutes". Because of that I chose `*/10 * * * *`. The reason why I asked how to set the `Time Range` is that I at first set a range of 24 hours and ran the alert every ten minutes and I got the results from yesterday twice as mail. That was one thing I wanted to avoid, therefore I set `Time Range` to 12 Minutes but I could also specify `earliest=-10m` then? I am a little afraid that I will miss some events

Comment: @Tobitor - you're right, I got my corn math backwards ...just made the fix in the answer :)

Comment: @Tobitor :: set the time range for the search in the search itself. For example, I have half-hourly Alerts running (`26,56 * * * *`) but in the *search* I set `earliest=-35m` because I'd rather have an *occasional* overlap in time sending a second Alert (it's only happened once in 18 months across dozens of similarly-formatted Alerts) than to miss one 

Comment: Ok, perfect! Thanks a lot :-)